# KineticJS creating a canvas

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am new to both JavaScript/Canvas and KineticJS.

I know that it is possible to create a canvas and a stage like this -

```
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
    </script>
```

But I was wondering if I already have a canvas, how will I create a stage out of it then? So something like this...

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
<script>
    //How do I create a Kinetic.stage of the #myCanvas?
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How about this:**

Create a new stage.

Create a new layer.

Create a new Image the same size as the stage.

Set the Image's image source to myCanvas.

Note: I didn't test the following code, but it should work +/- tweaks.

```
var myCanvasImg=new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d").toImageURL(),
      width: stage.getWidth(),
      height: stage.getHeight()
    });
```

Add the Image to the Layer and add the Layer to the Stage.

Bang...New stage with myCanvas contents!

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am looking to initialize my Kinetic Stage, but instead of creating the stage into container div, I do not want to create it but give it an existing canvas called myCanvas. I don't think the answer  is going to be this complicated, it is just that I am a newb and not explaining the question properly enough. sry about that. do ask for clarification if you do not understand what I am saying.

Comment: Note: myCanvas is comlpetely empty. It is not that I want to copy its content to stage.

Comment: Not complicated at all...can't be done in KineticJS the way you suggest!  Well, not without pulling apart the source code ;)

Comment: What I want to do is that I should have a reference to the canvas itself for use outside of KineticJS. Is there a way I can get the canvas and its context from the Kinetic.Stage?

Comment: Keep in mind that a stage is a container for multiple layers and every layer is a separate canvas.  So for any particular layer,  var context=myLayer.getContext() will get you the context from the layer.  Then context.canvas will get you the parent canvas.  But...what you get back from context.canvas is a **read-only** reference to the parent canvas.

Comment: Thats the knowledge I was missing. I never knew that. Sorry for confusing and bothering you with my newbieness. This comment definitely helps clear up things for me. Thanks.

Comment: No problems...everyone is a noob until we figure things out -- and then we're just noobs a something more complicated!

Comment: After consulting the docs (http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Layer.html), it seems to me that there is no way to associate an existing canvas to a Layer. Am I right? Can't you include a previously created canvas in a kineticjs as a layer?

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "associate".  Any prior non-Kinetic canvas is just a batch of pixels.  You can create a Kinetic layer and draw those pixels on that layer.  Then if you don't need that prior canvas anymore, you can destroy it. Also, you could use CSS to move that prior non-Kinetic canvas under the Kinetic stage--like a static background.   So...Yes, you can "associate" a prior non-Kinetic canvas with a Kinetic layer.  But the prior canvas element itself can't be made into a Kinetic layer.